# Why are most of the Avatars rulers?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, avatars

Why are main human avatars of God in the form of kings/ rulers/ princesses (lord Rama, Krishna)? Are there any "regular profession" avatars - eg teachers, householders, merchants?

Comment: Parshuram as Teacher, Vedvyas, कपिल मुनि Kapil avatar as  etc...http://www.ajabgjab.com/2014/08/24-avatars-incarnations-of-lord-vishnu.html

Comment: Lord Shiva will take a Yogeswara incarnation at the end of every Dwapara Yuga and teach people of Kaliyuga Yoga Techniques to liberate from cycle of birth and death. Till now He incarnated 28 times in this Mnavantara.

Answer (score 5):

The [**Shrimad Bhagvat Puran**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3) mentions 22 incarnations of Lord Vishnu and am sharing the list here:

> 1. Kumars – four yogis who live in the form of children
> 2. Varaha - non-human (boar)
> 3. Narad - the famous Devarishi
> 4. Nara-Narayan – twin-rishis
> 5. Kapil – another rishi
> 6. Dattatreya – an Avadhut and Yogi
> 7. Yajna – a previous Indra
> 8. Rishabh Dev – a king who turned into the first Jain Tirthankar
> 9. Prithu – the king after whom earth is called Prithvi
> 10. Matsya - non-human (fish)
> 11. Kurma - non-human (turtle)
> 12. Dhanvantari – physician & father of Ayurveda
> 13. Mohini – the only female incarnation
> 14. Narasimha - The man-lion
> 15. Vaman - a brahmin dwarf boy
> 16. Parashurama - another brahmin boy who became a kshatriya killer
> 17. Shri Rama - the 'Perfect King'
> 18. Ved Vyas – rishi who composed puranas, mahabharat and compiled Vedas.
> 19. Balarama - brother to Krishna and a prince
> 20. Krishna - the famous Yadav prince and expounder of Bhagvad Geeta
> 21. Buddha - a prince who became a yogi
> 22. Kalki - The future avatar who would be born to a brahmin Vishnuyash

As you can see from the above list there are only three proper kings - **Prithu, Rishabh Dev & Shri Rama**. You may add Krishna but Yadavs did not really have a kingdom rather they thrived as a confederacy whose leader was Ugrasen.

If you notice, the majority of non-animal avatars are non-kshatriya - **Dattatreya, Narad, Dhanvantari, Nar, Narayan, Vyas, Kapil, Vaman, Parshurama, & Kalki** are non rulers event though the last two do pick up arms for the benefit of the society. So based on the scriptures, the contention of a majority of Avatars being rulers does not appear to be correct.

Comment: Very nice compilation sir.